# MSBuild <FileWrites> item doesn't do anything

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Brian Kretzler’s book explains how `<FileWrites>` is used to remember what was actually written so cleaning can work even if the exact files has changed since the build.  But, it doesn't do anything for me.

Inside a `Target`, I have

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FileWrites Include="@(QtUICompile->'$(GeneratedDir)/ui_%(Filename).h)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

in one case, where the @-expression is exactly the same as used for Outputs, and

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FileWrites Include="@(QtResourceOutput)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

in another case where the item array `QtResourceOutput` is created first and used for both the Outputs and here, and is also used in a `Message` so I can see that it is getting the file name right, and the feature of noticing that outputs are up-to-date works correctly.

When I do a Clean of the solution (or of a project that caused these targets to be performed before its `ClCompile` task), those files are not removed.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to troubleshoot this feature?

Answer (score 2):

I've learned that the `FileWrites` item list is not used in C++ projects.  To troubleshoot, I used the `--preprocess`/`/preprocess` MSBuild option and looked for uses of `FileWrites` in the flattened project file.  The cleaning pathway did not use it, and it appeared that `ClCompile` did not use it (not in the XML script anyway; it might still do odd things inside the Task I later learned)